# I am getting this error when umploading aab to Google play console : You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias

Tags: android, xamarin, android-manifest, google-play-console

issue : You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set

I am working on a project in Xamarin that has been derived from me. It's my first time working with xamarin and I'm trying to push an update to the store. When uploading the aab to the store I get the following message. I have been reading several solutions but none has just worked. I attach my AndroidManfiest.xml, AssemblyInfo.cs and MainActivity.cs

AndroidManifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.4" package="ad.test.test" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:versionCode="7">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="30" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label="test.Android" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="false" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

AssemblyInfo :

```
    using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Android.App;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("test.Android")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("test.Android")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Application(Debuggable = false)]
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

// Add some common permissions, these can be removed if not needed
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
```

MainActivity :

```
    using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using PanCardView.Droid;
using Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh.Droid;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using test.Core;

namespace test.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "test", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true,Exported = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(enableFastRenderer:true);
            CardsViewRenderer.Preserve();
            UserDialogs.Init(this);
            PullToRefreshLayoutRenderer.Init();
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LeoJHarris.FormsPlugin.Droid.EnhancedEntryRenderer.Init(this);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            //FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
            //CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("general");
            //CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();




            //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                //Change for your default notification channel id here
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "FirebasePushNotificationChannel";

                //Change for your default notification channel name here
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";
            }


            //If debug you should reset the token each time.
#if DEBUG
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
#else
              FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,false);
#endif
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("general");
            //Handle notification when app is closed here
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");
            };

        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, intent);
        }

        void SetFullscreen()
        {
            var uiOptions = (int)Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
           
          // uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
            //  uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
            //  uiOptions = (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
            //  uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;

        //   Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility =   (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
        //
         //   Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)(int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;

         //   Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn, WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
        }
        /*
       
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            this.OnPause();

            foreach (WebView webView in AppSettings.getWebViews())
            {

                webView.Source="";
            }

           //if it's not webview in your case then add the method name you want pause when user device is pause
        }


        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            this.OnResume();
          //  myWebView.onResume();//same as here if it's not webview then add the method name you want to resume when user resume their device
        }
        */

    }
}
```

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following property to your receiver and activity:

```
Exported =true
```